# Python cmd interpreter adding if statements

Tags: python, sql, control-flow

For one of my projects I have a python program built around the python [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) class. This allowed me to craft a mini language around sql statements that I was sending to a database. Besides making it far easier to connect with python, I could do things that sql can't do. This was very important for several projects. However, I now need to add in if blocks for greater control flow.

My current thinking is that I will just add two new commands to the language, IF and END. These set a variable which determines whether or not to skip a line. I would like to know if anyone else has done this with the cmd module, and if so, is there a standard method I'm missing? Google doesn't seem to reveal anything, and the cmd docs don't reveal anything either.

For an idea that's similar to what I'm doing, go [here](http://blog.fogcreek.com/cheeky-python-a-redis-cli/). Questions and comments welcome. :)

Hmm, a little more complicated than what I was thinking, though having python syntax would be nice. I debated building a mini language for quite some time before I finally did it. The problem primarily comes in from the external limitations. I have a bunch of "data", which is being generous, to turn into sql. This is based on other "data" that won't pass through. It's also unique to each specific "version" of the problem. Doing straight data to sql would have been my first inclination, but was not practical.

For the curious, I spent a great deal of time going over the mini languages chapter in the art of unix programming, found [here](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/minilanguageschapter.html).

If I had built the thing in pure python, I wouldn't have had the flexibility I absolutely needed for the problem set.

Comment: "I wouldn't have had the flexibility I absolutely needed for the problem set."  That can't possibly be true.  Your DSL has fewer features than Python and you now require *additional* features.  You still don't have a Turing Complete language in your DSL, so you are sacrificing flexibility.  Also, if you rebuild it to be pure Python, you sacrifice nothing.  And you gain better syntax.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in there, but one of the major constraints is that I have to insert data into the database, then based upon data I get out, make some decisions, and insert some more data, based upon the data I got out. The mini language is mostly just a wrapper around python to the database, handling each piece of functionality as an atomic unit. I would have implemented it as just functions, but I needed to mix and match them based upon today's problem, allow for an interactive mode, handle some prework, and break the thing out of another program.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun: Nothing changes when you switch from `cmd` to proper Python.  Nothing is lost.  No feature is lost.  No functionality is lost.  Only the syntax changes.

Comment: Of course not, that isn't the point. Proper python is not sql. I didn't want to be on the command line and type:

Comment: Darn enter button. In its entirety: Of course not, that isn't the point. Behind the scenes, it IS python. The point of the mini language was to give me legos, rather than atoms for doing something else entirely. I've now found myself in the position of needing a new lego. So, I wanted to see if anyone else had a better configuration of atoms than what I came up with. I don't need, and specifically do not want full blown control flow. Your solution has me moving away from my driver in car with controls paradigm, to a man hovering over the engine twiddling the carburetor.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun:  Your syntax changes from `foo argumentstring` to `foo( "argumentstring" )`.  That's all.  That's the only change.  And you then have full Python if statements for that almost inconsequential change.

Comment: @S.Lott It seems I misread your answer, my apologies. I'm not entirely sure it will work though, as the thing handles various runtime variable sets. That was part of the reason I created it, so I could abstract away that portion of the problem. If your changes don't break that, then it seems I will have a far more powerful solution than I came looking for. My hat is off, sir.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun: It **cannot** break anything.  The only thing you really need to think about is the fact that the `cmd.Cmd` instance variables (accessed via `self.whatever`) is replaced by an explicit `self.context` object that's explicitly shared among the command objects.  (`self.whatever` becomes `self.context.whatever`.) Other than that, your implementation changes very little and your command syntax changes microscopically.  `("args")`.

Comment: @S.Lott it seemed that way from your answer. I've been burned before by things that are just supposed to work though. I'll test it and see. If it doesn't work, I can always revert back to the previous version in the repository.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun: "burned before by things that are just supposed to work".  You've already written all the code.  And it all works.  All you're doing is breaking one subclass of `cmd.Cmd` into separate subclasses with explicit shared state.  It can't be done without *some* actual thinking.  But you've already done all the work.  It's a small refactoring of code which you can easily unit test.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After examining the problem set some more, I've come to the conclusion that I can leave the minilanguage alone. It has all the features I need, and I don't have the time to rebuild the project from the ground up. This has been an interesting problem and I'm no longer sure I would build another minilanguage if I encountered the same situation. OTOH, it works very well here, and I am loathe to give up the advantages it has conferred.

Answer (score 1):

The limitations of making a "mini language" have become apparent.

Proper languages have a tree-like structure and more complex syntax than `cmd` can handle easily.

Sometimes it's actually easier to use Python directly than it is to invent your own DSL.

Currently, your DSL probably reads a script-like file of commands.

Because of the way `cmd` works, your little comments get a string argument, which must be parsed.  Then the command gets executed.  And, further, each command is a method of the `cmd.Cmd` subclass.

Here's what you can do.

Each `do_foo( self, args )` method becomes a stand-alone callable object.  It will follow the **Command** design pattern.  It will do **exactly** what the method function does now.   No less.  **Exactly** the same.

```
class Foo( object ):
    def __init__( self, global_context ):
        self.context= global_context
    def __call__( self, args ):
        ... The rest of do_foo ...
```

Additionally, your existing `cmd.Cmd` subclass probably maintains some internal state.
All of the `self.this` and `self.that` instance variables must be changed to reference
and explicit context object.

```
class Context( object ): pass
```

Change `self.this` or `self.that` to `self.context.this` or `self.context.that`

Now, you can create your context and your various commands.

```
ctx = Context()
foo= Foo(ctx)
```

Your script changes syntax slightly. From:

```
foo argstring
bar argstring
```

to:

```
from mylanguage import foo, bar
foo( "argstring" )
bar( "argstring" )
```

This does **Exactly** what the CLI does now.  No more.  No less.  **Exactly** the same.  Slightly different syntax.

Now your script is no longer in a DSL that's hard to expand.  It's in Python.

Having done that, you can now use Python syntax `if` statements.

You have the **Exact** functionality currently implemented in `cmd` with better syntax.